# Database switching based on database load in MVC application and hosting your sites on multiple IIS server for site load balancing

Tags: sql-server, iis, web-deployment

I have been asked this question on my recent interview for .Net architect role. I have no clue on this. I tried to search in the internet but did not find any satisfying solution. Let me try to explain the scenario in detail.

Consider travel website like yatra.com or MakeMyTrip, millions of people hitting it on daily basis. What if loads of database has increased a lot and performance is down. We can set up multiple database instances in multiple servers but how it can be switch at run-time considering the load on the one database to the other database. How people handles such type of situations in big web applications with millions of users.

Another question is kind of same, If the load on IIS server is more, then how we can redirect the request from one IIS server to another IIS server (Note: considering we have created multiple virtual directories on IIS server in the multiple servers ).

If you guys know some good articles on this or any book, kindly share the same to me. Thanks in advance.